# Реализация множества списков N объектов из списка M объектов

Tags: java, рекурсия, перебор

Застопорился на таком вопросе. Есть массив/список/что угодно из 5 объектов. Необходимо перебрать (рекурсивно в идеале) все варианты списка из 20 объектов, в котором будут в рандомном порядке элементы из первого массива.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(obj1);
objects.add(obj2);
objects.add(obj3);
objects.add(obj4);
objects.add(obj5);

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); //список из 20 элементов, в который кидаются 5 элементов objects
```

На выходе должен получать список, выполнять с ним работу и генерировать новый список пока не переберу все варианты

Буду благодарен любой информации

Comment: Всех вариантов 5^20, это сто триллионов. Может, какие ограничения есть?

Comment: Ограничения будут в одну строчку для 99%. Хотелось бы понять как составить алгоритм перебора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всего будет `5^20` вариантов (`M^N`).

Все их сгенерировать можно, но довольно долго.

Можно воспользоваться представлением комбинации как числа от `0` до `M^N-1` в M-ричной системе счисления.

Если нужны все варианты - проходим в цикле с указанными пределами, и ставим в соответствие счётчику определённую комбинацию.

Если нужны случайные варианты- генерируем случайное число в указанных пределах и опять же делаем соответствующую ему  комбинацию

```
i - номер комбинации
t = i
for (k = 0; k < N; k++)  {
    idx = t % M
    list[k] = objects[idx]   
    t = t / M
}
```